# GitHub actions: Error when deleting the branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I set a GitHub action as follow:

```
# https://github.com/actions/stale
name: 'Close stale issues and PRs'
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 9 * * *'
permissions:
  # All other permissions are set to none
  issues: write
  pull-requests: write
jobs:
  stale:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/stale@v4
        with:
          repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          stale-pr-message: >
            This pull request has been automatically marked as stale because it has not had recent activity.
          days-before-pr-stale: 90
          days-before-pr-close: 5
          exempt-pr-labels: 'pinned'
          remove-pr-stale-when-updated: true
          delete-branch: true
          ascending: true
          operations-per-run: 50
```

The action works great for commeting on PR, labelling and closing.
However the `delete-branch: true` doesn't seem to work.
Looking at the action log I see:

```
�[97m�[34m[#1288]�[39m Error when deleting the branch "�[36fixingissue�[39m" from pull request: Resource not accessible by integration�[39m
```

Noting that the action has `pull-requests: write` and it manages to label PR, comment on it and close it but not to delete the branch.

The documentation https://github.com/actions/stale#delete-branch says that `Required Permission: pull-requests: write` so this should work.

What is the problem?

Comment: Did you try using a Personal Access Token (PAT) instead of the GITHUB_TOKEN? They have different scopes so it might be related to the token permissions.

Comment: @GuiFalourd no. but GitHub doesn't show the need for a specific permission for deleting a branch nor does the documentation of the action

Comment: According to the action documentation (link: https://github.com/actions/stale#repo-token) they recommend to use the PAT. And as you used a secrets using the GITHUB_ prefix syntax (which is not recommended by the Github Actions doc (link: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#naming-your-secrets) I would suggest to create a PAT, add it to your repo secrets using a name such as ACCESS_TOKEN and then use this secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN as variable in your workflow. Let me know if it resolve your issue :)